# Could not load com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tomcat8

We have created a listener using Javamail api to read the newly added message in the email inbox.  Once the listener received the new message, we are trying to fetch all the header information as well as content part. For parsing the content, we have written a proper parsing logic and it's working fine for all type of content(text,html,multipart etc.). Here is the parsing code.

```
private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            String s = (String) p.getContent();         
            return s;
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null){
                        text = getText(bp);
                        return text;
                    }

                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                    return s;

                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The above listener and parsing, we are running in a web application which is deployed in a tomcat container (version - Apache tomcat 8.0.35).

After some time when we are getting session time out for a IMAP connection, we are restarting the listener by programmatic. Now the listener is able to read the newly added message to the inbox, but the message content parsing is failing the following exception. We have tried multiple option to fix the issue, but didn't get a success. Below is the exception stack trace

```
25-Mar-2016 14:08:10.158 INFO [JavaMail-EventQueue] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1316)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:582)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:560)
    at javax.activation.CommandMap.createDataContentHandler(CommandMap.java:221)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:615)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:542)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1419)
    at omniquo.awe.util.MailUtil.readMailBody(MailUtil.java:152)
    at omniquo.awe.activitiservice.MailListner$MailThreadListener$2.messagesAdded(MailListner.java:165)
    at javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent.dispatch(MessageCountEvent.java:150)
    at javax.mail.EventQueue.run(EventQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Unable to parse Email com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
    at omniquo.awe.util.MailUtil.readMailBody(MailUtil.java:152)
    at omniquo.awe.activitiservice.MailListner$MailThreadListener$2.messagesAdded(MailListner.java:165)
    at javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent.dispatch(MessageCountEvent.java:150)
    at javax.mail.EventQueue.run(EventQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We need a concrete solution to fix this. We are using the following environment and api versions

JDK- 1.8.0_65, 
Tomcat - 8.0.35, 
Java mail - 1.5.5, 
Spring - 4

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand why this would start failing if **nothing changed**.  You really need to figure out what changed.  Are you using a newer version of the JDK or Tomcat?

What exactly do you mean by "restarting the listener by programmatic"?  Are you restarting the Tomcat server?

This problem usually occurs because the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF, now a part of the JDK) is unable to find the configuration file that describes what Java class to use for what MIME type.  This configuration file is a part of the JavaMail jar file.  If your application was changed and this file was lost, that would explain it.  It can also happen due to problems with the ClassLoader if you're using some unusual class loading scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the webapp then the [javax.mail.EventQueue](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/EventQueue.java?rev=812) is capturing the first webapp classloader.  When new threads are created the context classloader is set to the context classloader of the parent thread.

```
synchronized void enqueue(MailEvent event, Vector vector) {
    // if this is the first event, create the queue and start the event task
    if (q == null) {
        q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<QueueElement>();
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.execute(this);
        } else {
            Thread qThread = new Thread(this, "JavaMail-EventQueue");
            qThread.setDaemon(true);  // not a user thread
            qThread.start();
        }
    }
    q.add(new QueueElement(event, vector));
}
```

Modify your [MessageCountListener](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.html) to set the context class loader:

```
public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    //Your existing code....
}
```